# Populate woocommerce_wp_select field from database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select, woocommerce

please help me out with this..I've tried too many different things... 
I'm trying to populate a woocommerce select field with data from the database.

```
// Add fields & settings to the custom product tab
$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM wp_lbc_prices";
$array = $wpdb->get_results( $SQL, ARRAY_A);


add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 
'wcpt_roller_blind_options_product_tab_content' );

function wcpt_roller_blind_options_product_tab_content() {

?><div id='roller_blind_options' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'><?php
    ?><div class='options_group'><?php
        woocommerce_wp_select( array(
                'id'          => 'roller_blind_tables',
                'label'       => __( 'Price Tables', 'wcpt' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => __( 'Select Associated Price Table.', 'wcpt' ),
                'options' => $array
           ));

    ?></div>
</div><?php
```

Certainly, the query to the DB works and a result is being returned... but I'm not sure how to make an acceptable array (I'm used to asp.net which seems to make this more simple!). The data I am returning does not need an ID so the value and text of the dropdown can be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need **first to be sure of `table_name` or replace it by the correct column slug** to be queried from your database table `wp_lbc_prices`.
2. You need to replace the `WPDB` method `get_results()` by `get_col()`which query a single column and gives an array natively.
3. Prepare the array to copying the values to the keys using `array_combine()`

I have completed your code with the hooked function that adds a custom product tab.

Your revisited code will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'add_roller_blind_product_data_tab' );
function add_roller_blind_product_data_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['roller_blind'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Roller blind', 'wcpt' ),
        'target' => 'roller_blind_options', // <== to be used in the <div> class of the content
        //'class' => array('show_if_simple'), // or 'hide_if_simple' or 'show_if_variable'…
    );

    return $tabs;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'display_roller_blind_product_data_tab_content' );
function display_roller_blind_product_data_tab_content() {
    global $wpdb;

    echo '<div id="roller_blind_options" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
    <div class="options_group">';

    $sql_query = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wp_lbc_prices" );
    $options   = sizeof($sql_query) > 0 ? array_combine( $sql_query, $sql_query ) : array();

    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'          => 'roller_blind_tables',
        'label'       => __( 'Price Tables', 'wcpt' ),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Select Associated Price Table.', 'wcpt' ),
        'options'     => $options
    ));

    echo '</div></div>';
}
```

It should better work now. But as this is a custom database table is not testable.

Comment: Thanks so much! The code works great, and you've given me some additional methods to look into and use for the future. And thanks also for the explainations.

Answer (score 0):

get_results function return an array with indexes so the values can be like array of objects like this `array([0]=>object,[1]=>object)` can you please share what you are getting in $array variable ?